# Moving sidebar links to below the header menu

Tags: plugins

This is my first question on StackExchange.
I'm using a Wordpress plugin that shows links to pages in the sidebar. Now my question is, how can I move them to below the top menu?

example site: http://www.androidos.in/products/phone/sony-xperia-zr/

In the sidebar below the image you can notice some links, i want to make that like this:
http://www.engadget.com/products/samsung/galaxy/s/4/

In the above site you can notice above the image some links i want to make it like that.

```
.gdpc-side {
     float: left;
     width: 182px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
.gdpc-side h2 {
    clear: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aa0000;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #aa0000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.gdpc-side .main-image {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.gdpc-side ul.gdpc-links {
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.gdpc-side .gdpc-companies,
.gdpc-side .gdpc-taxonomies {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.gdpc-side .gdpc-companies h5,
.gdpc-side .gdpc-taxonomies h5{
    margin: 0px;
}
.gdpc-side .gdpc-archive-link {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that this plugin adds a widget that you put in sidebar so edit your page.php and add a sidebar on the top where you can add this widget with those links.

```
register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => __( 'Phone Extra Info' ),
  'id' => 'phone-info-sidebar',
  'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on top of a page' ),
));
```

of course you can add all the before and after widget arguments that the array takes. See the reference for more.

**Reference:**

- [register_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

Comment: above i'm giving actual css files for that sidebar

Comment: Just register the sidebar in the place you wish the links to appear and then style them as you wish. This is not a CSS forum - you will not get an answer on how to style them to look good.